# Change selected value div from one wrapper to another wrapper on selected option div

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

```
<div class="zones-riders-wrapper">
    <div class="zones-rider-header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h5 class="rider-name">@drv.Drivername</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="rider-trips">Weight/Trip (@drv.DriverCapacity)</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="zones-filters">
        <select>
            <option>Move To</option>
            @foreach (var drvName in Model.zoneDriver.Where(x => x.ZoneName == item.ZoneName))
            {
                <option>
                    @drvName.Drivername
                </option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="zones-trips-body" class="zones-trips-body">
        @foreach (var ord in Model.orderDetails.Where(x => x.ZoneName == item.ZoneName && x.DriverId == drv.DriverId))
        {
        <input class="zoneBodyId" type="hidden" value="@drv.DriverId" />
        <div class="zones-trip">
            @*<input type="checkbox" />*@
            <label for="chkIsActive">
                <div class="zone-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="IsActive" class="chkIsActive" class="switch">
                    <div class="zone-check-overlay"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="zone-order-id">
                    <label>Order ID</label>
                    <span>@ord.OrderId</span>
                </div>
                <div class="zone-order-receiver">
                    <label>Receiver Name</label>
                    <span>@ord.RecieverName</span>
                </div>
                <div class="zone-order-sender">
                    <label>Receiver Add.</label>
                    <span>@ord.RecieverAddress</span>
                </div>

            </label>
        </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(".zones-trip").click(function () {
    $(this).find(".chkIsActive").click();
    var zoneBox = $(this).closest(".zones-trip").html();
    console.log(zoneBox);
    //$(this).remove();
     
 });
 $(document).on("change", ".zones-filters select", function () {
    var selectValue = $(".zones-filters select option:selected").val();
    console.log(selectValue);
 });
```

CSS:

```
.zone-check {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.zone-check input[type=checkbox] {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 22px;
}
.zone-check input[type=checkbox]:checked + .zone-check-overlay {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.5242471988795518) 18%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
}
    .zone-check input[type=checkbox]:checked {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 1;
    }
.zones-trip {
    position: relative;
}
```

this is my code, can anyone help me, I have stuck in this thing.

I have a checkbox and I have to select checkbox first then When I select rider name from dropdown, The selected div will move to selected rider list.
I have added snapshot in which the frontend is clear, thanks in advance , waiting for reply

please check the below image link
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx4iq.png

Comment: It would be better if you include the rendered code from your page, also please include all relevant code like css, jquery

Comment: Carsten, I have updated my code with CSS and jQuery, please check now

Comment: Hi, @NabeelMYousuf you want just move order one div to selected div correct?

Comment: yes @Jishan

not only order 1, my selected checked div will move to the selected rider body

Comment: Okay, @NabeelMYousuf can you please add sours of HTML above code dynamic for each and model property present. just inspect then HTML click to copy and add here so anyone can add an answer.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/uhk0pw
@Jishan